# Should a misleading but informative question be closed?

Tags: discussion

I have my own question:

[PXE boot windows PE from Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/708032/pxe-boot-windows-pe-from-linux)

Which seems to contribute useful information on how to PXE windows from a Linux server, however the issue I personally experienced was a result of a bad FTP-get (so the windows PE didn't boot because the FTP client I used didn't grab the whole thing).

On one hand, questions that are a result of minor user errors such as typos are considered off topic. On the other hand I feel like the question/answer provides useful information.

I can't delete the question, because it has an upvoted answer (I probably upvoted the answer). I'm not sure it would be good to delete it either because the question is also upvoted, suggesting someone found it useful.

So is there an action that should be taken on the question? Should it be marked as closed? Should I include an edit stating that the issue was simply from an FTP-get error, and that there wasn't an issue in the method used? Or should I just leave it be?

Answer (score 8):

Writing your own answer stating what you found to be the problem is perfectly fine, even if is your own error. This can be helpful to others because it's possible someone does the same thing wrong and don't notice it - if they search for the symptoms, they will hopefully find your post and find it helpful.

This is also true for minor typos and stuff like that. Minor errors can have subtle and hard to understand consequences and there is no shame at all in admitting you overlooked a minor issue and found it only after posting a question. I specifically wouldn't consider such questions off-topic.

As for the  question at hand: Write your own answer, unaccept the posted one and accept your own and all should be fine.

Comment: I went ahead and wrote a small answer stating the error.